# PHP 500 Internal Server Error due to a SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have a php script that shows `500 Internal Server Error` if the ff lines are on a query.

```
 CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 301, 4)) as BINARY(4))) AS maxexperience
```

When I remove that, all will work well.

```
$SQL = "SELECT TOP 10
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring(char_data, 9, 16)) AS name,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 7, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS level,
    CONVERT(INT,substring(char_data, 25, 1)) AS type,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 263, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS strength,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 265, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS wisdom,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 267, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS dexterity,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 269, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS charisma,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 271, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS intelligence,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 273, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS constitution,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 309, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS fame,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 301, 4)) as BINARY(4))) AS maxexperience
FROM CHAR_DATA0 WHERE CONVERT(INT, substring(char_data, 261, 1))=0x00 ORDER BY level DESC";
```

I tried running the same script from MSSMS - 2008

```
 name       level   type    strength  wisdom  dexterity  charisma   intelligence    constitution    fame    maxexperience
 ladycharm  340     4       3510      1210    5200       2001       1120            4236            14265   1782451348
```

It does work. But from the php script it gives out an error.
Please advice? Thank you.

--- error logs on cpanel ---

```
 [Sat Jul 28 13:01:24 2012] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /home/blazegam/public_html/test/404.shtml
 [Sat Jul 28 13:01:24 2012] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /home/blazegam/public_html/test/favicon.ico
 [Sat Jul 28 13:00:38 2012] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /home/blazegam/public_html/test/404.shtml
 [Sat Jul 28 13:00:38 2012] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /home/blazegam/public_html/test/favicon.ico
```

Checked all the logs even tried making a script that should error. I saw the error for that script. But not for this script. It didnt log an error.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to normalize that table so you don't have to do all that horrible manipulation every query?

Comment: Look in your error log for the actual error. Is this MS SQL? Use `mssql_get_last_message()` in code to see errors too

Comment: Normalizing would be out of the question though. Cant change the design.

Comment: Yes, I tried catching the error by using that on php. But it just displays 500 internal error. I'm using cPanel, know where the logs can be found?

Comment: Turn on error_reporting, then check the log again... `error_reporting(E_ALL);` or display on screen with `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: No luck with displaying any error logs for the script. Added ini_set to the script. still 500 ISE.

Comment: What if you pear the query down to a single row, test, and re-add back until you localize which line it is? Or if it's the whole thing?

Comment: Its just that one line I specified on my question.

Comment: Try unwrapping the brackets one at a time until the error goes away (start with the `substring` and work out)

Comment: Somehow I doubt SQL error would generate error 500 except if php script is configured to send error 500 header if something goes wrong. Are you perhaps exceeding memory or time limits?

Comment: You say `lines`, but is it literally *just the one* or any of those like lines?

Comment: Instead of removing column `maxexperience`, try with removing column `fame`. I mean remove the entire line having the expression of the column. Is it working?

Answer (score 1):

That's some crazy SQL ... but I don't think it's the source of your "error 500".

In fact, I think the root cause might be HTTP 404: File not found:

`File does not exist: /home/blazegam/public_html/test/404.shtml`

Instead, I think:

1) the client is requesting an invalid link

2) The server tries ... and fails ... to generate an error 404

3) Ultimately, the client receives back an error 500

Q: Are you *sure* you're calling the right server-side file and directory?

PS:
I don't know why w0rldart deleted his response.  But for purposes of debugging, enabling full error reporting is actually a pretty good idea:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP CLI, try debugging with this from the command line:

```
php -l /path/to/your/php_script.php
```

9 times out of 10 for me, 500 status codes are from a little syntax error... Can you perhaps paste the actual querying block of code in your PHP file? I see you pasted the query string you're using, but it'll help to see more.